# Why do I get horizontal overflow/scrolling depending on the inspector?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, web-inspector

Here's the page I'm working on : https://codingwilsona.github.io/ProtoToWeb/

When I use the inspector with the device toolbar toggled on, starting at a width > 1300px and then shrink it down to a smartphone width (lower than 470px), everything's fine.

If I close the web page and reopen it again, the inspector will resume with the latest settings previously used (width < 470px) but the web page is displayed with a horizontal overflow/scrolling and I have no idea why.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself...

The viewport meta tag was missing "user-scalable=no"

Sorry for the inconvenience